# How do I create two popups with avgrund, without making them display at the same time?

Tags: javascript, css, popup, modal-dialog, avgrund

I'm trying to create two popups with the js library [Avgrund](http://lab.hakim.se/avgrund/). The problem is that whenever I have two forms on the same page, both of them are activated whenever the activate function is called.

To summarize the javascript- a user presses either a login or signup button, and causes for the following to be called:

```
    function activate( state , selector ) {

    var popup = document.querySelector( selector );

    document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'click', onDocumentClick, false );

    removeClass( popup, currentState );
    addClass( popup, 'no-transition' );
    addClass( popup, state );

    setTimeout( function() {
        removeClass( popup, 'no-transition' );
        addClass( container, 'avgrund-active' );
    }, 0 );

    currentState = state;
}
```

this will add the 'active' class to the form, and cause the signature avgrund transition and popup to be displayed- **for both forms**. The purpose of the querySelector is to modify only the aside element with the specific id(selector) associated with it. This is supposed to cause only the **form with the specific id(either '#login' or '#signup') to popup**.

The classes of the aside elements(the login and signin forms) are changed according to each of the buttons- but both display popups. Lastly- one of the forms is always shows on top of the other one.

Here is a simplified version of the problem in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqepn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Avgrund jQuery plugin for this. It's a more cross-browser safe and flexible wrapper for the origin Avgrund concept.

http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js

Answer (score 1):

You could load the second popup in the onUnload property of the first one (using the [Avgrund jquery plugin](http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/)).

**jQuery code**

```
$("#first").avgrund({
    onUnload: function (elem) {
        $('#second').click();
    },
    template: 'first popup'
});

$("#second").avgrund({
    template: 'second popup'
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="first">Open first popup</a>
<a href="#" id="second" style="display:none;">Open second popup</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the modal of Avgrund as follows

**JavaScript**

```js
function openDialog() {
  Avgrund.show("#default-popup");
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="javascript:openDialog();">Open Avgrund</button>
  <aside id="default-popup" class="avgrund-popup">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <p>...</p>
    <button onclick="javascript:closeDialog();">Close</button>
  </aside>
</body>
```

[Source](https://github.com/hakimel/avgrund): https://github.com/hakimel/avgrund